# Updating collection view (necessity of calling performBatchUpdates)?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am attempting to insert (and later delete) items from a collection view, which sits inside a tableview. When inserting items into the collection view, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 items in section 0 after the update'
```

I have read many other posts that say the issue is that the collection view data source is not being updated before attempting to insert items into the collection view, so there is an inconsistency between size of the two. My collection view data source is an array of strings, which I get from a text box that the user can type into. When the user hits return on the keyboard, I want to add whatever they typed into the collection view. So, I have the following method:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchedItemsArray.append(textField.text!)
    searchedItems.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: searchedItemsArray.count - 1, section: 0)])
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

where searchedItemsArray is the data source, and searchedItems is the collection view. As you can see, I do update the data source before the collection view. I have also verified that the string is correctly appended to the collection view. When the user enters the first item, I printed the size of the array and verified that it was 1 before the collectionView.insert() method is called.

I also have this method for the collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchedItemsArray.count
}
```

The sense I got from other answers is that the collection view and data source must be getting out of sync, but I am confused where this is actually happening.

Another possible solution I saw is to user performBatchUpdates(), but that seems unnecessary since I am updating a single thing in the collectionView.

Comment: What happens when you print `searchedItemsArray.count` in `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)`? If nothing is printed, set the dataSource.

Comment: are you calling 'collectionView.reloadData()' anywhere?

Comment: @Don thank you, I had forgotten to set the data source.